# Should I block HTTP 1.0 request?

Tags: php, security, nginx

I use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] for absolute url paths in my website. But, often, I find nginx error logs of HTTP/1.0 requests with undefined HTTP_HOST.

Is it advisable to block these requests? What's the best way to block them?

Comment: Belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't get it. E.g. a markup language like HTML is on topic, but protocol specifics not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it advisable to block these requests?

If your application cannot serve anything meaningful without the host, then it's IMO advisable. Furthermore I couldn't find anything in HTTP 1.1 which says applications have to be backward compatible.

> What's the best way to block them?

Answer them with [`505 HTTP Version Not Supported`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.6).